# Permutations with repetition using recursion - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, recursion, permutation

I'm working on a recursive algorithm that takes in an array with three different elements (say `['a', 'b', 'c']` and returns a two-dimensional array with all the possible variations with repetition allowed (so `[['a', 'a', 'a'], ['a', 'a', 'b'], ['a', 'b', 'b'],...]`). However my code fails and I'm not sure why.

```
var abc = function () {
  var holdingArr = [];
  var threeOptions = ["a", "b", "c"];
  var singleSolution = [];  
  var recursiveABC = function(arr) {
      if (singleSolution.length > 2) {
        holdingArr.push(singleSolution);
        singleSolution = [];
        return;
      }
      for (var i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        recursiveABC(arr.slice(i+1));
      }
  };
  recursiveABC(threeOptions);
  return holdingArr;
};
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're not looking for a complete working implementation but rather the errors in your code. Here are some I found:

1. You are not keeping variable names consistent: `holdingArray` vs `holdingArr`.
2. You never actually push anything into `singleSolution`.

Edit: Here's a working implementation, based on your original code.

```
var abc = function () {
  var holdingArr = [];
  var threeOptions = ["a", "b", "c"];
  var recursiveABC = function(singleSolution) {
      if (singleSolution.length > 2) {
        holdingArr.push(singleSolution);
        return;
      }
      for (var i=0; i < threeOptions.length; i++) {
        recursiveABC(singleSolution.concat([threeOptions[i]]));
      }
  };
  recursiveABC([]);
  return holdingArr;
};
```

You basically want each recursive function call to work on its own copy of `singleSolution`, rather than keeping a common one in closure scope. And, since we are iterating over the options rather than the solution so far, there is no need to have the recursive function take the options as a parameter.

Comment: Thank you. #1 was just a transcription typo (fixed). #2 is a good question...not sure what (and where) I should be pushing into `singleSolution`...And sorry I wasn't clearer but I **am** looking for a working implementation that uses recursion.